# Content in PickerView not showing up

Tags: ios, swift

I am new with programming in Swift. i got problem when i want to show up 2 different picker with 2 different content. But it show (?) instead of content.

see the screenshoot below

[image]

Thank your for help!

```
let fruit = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "banana", "peach", "strawberry"]
let food = ["rice","bread","spagheti","milk"]


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        return fruit.count
    }
    else {
        return food.count
    }
}    

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        return fruit[row]
    }
    else {
        return food[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set the `datasource` _and_ `delegate`

Comment: I already set them up.

Comment: @fnsmp, You clearly mentioned in your comment that you already set `Delegate` & `DataSource` to your PickerView then how could you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven’t set your pickers’ delegates and data sources.

First add these protocols to your ViewController subclass

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

then in `viewDidLoad` set delegates and data sources of your pickers as `self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView1.delegate = self
    pickerView1.dataSource = self
    pickerView2.delegate = self
    pickerView2.dataSource = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check you pickerView `DataSource` and `Delegate` connected properly and then you can conditionally load data by comparing pickerView like below.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == YOUR_FIRST_PICKER {
        return fruit.count
    }
    else {
        return food.count
    }
}    

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == YOUR_FIRST_PICKER {
        return fruit[row]
    }
    else {
        return food[row]
    }
}
```